# Facebook PHP SDK vs Third party Python SDK

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-sdk-3.1

I need Facebook API for my web app. Official Facebook only provide API in Android, IOS, JavaScript, PHP etc but not in Python. There are third party SDK's available for Python. What should i use PHP SDK (which is official by Facebook ) or Third party Python SDK.
I cannot compromise on scalability of app. Will third party python API be slower then PHP API in case of Facebook data fetching.

Comment: Are you using Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Django-facebook](https://github.com/tschellenbach/Django-facebook) in my django projects. I recommend its use because it's an active github project and you can also contribute to it whenever you want/need.

Comment: I want to fetch post of different groups that i have joined via API. Will Django-facebook will help?

Comment: Yes. You can do it with simple commands. Something like: facebook.get('GROUP_ID_HERE/posts'), where facebook is your OpenFacebook object. You can also check the documentation here: http://django-facebook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/open_facebook/api.html